# Error found in the code to recursively add number with its reverse till it becomes a pallindrom

Tags: python-3.x

i want to perform recursive addition to get a palindrome
If the number is 1234 - > 1234 + 4321 -> 5555 which is a pallindrome
if the number is 1473 -> 1473 +3741 ->5214 + 4125 -> 9339

Everytime the number is added to its reverse and checked if the answer is pallindrome

My code is:

```
num=int(input())
ans=0
rev=0
lst1=[]
lst2=[]
lst3=[]
while ans!=num:
    temp=num
    while temp>0:
        rev=temp%10+rev*10
        temp=temp/10
    num=num+rev
    lst1=list(map(int,str(num)))
    lst2=lst1
    lst3=lst2[::-1]
    if lst1==lst2 :
        ans=num

print(ans)
```

The error that i am getting is :

```
lst1=list(map(int,str(num)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'i'
```

I am new to Python any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think this is in part down to the fact you are thinking int/int = int.. result is  not a whole number.. so while temp > 0 may not be giving you what you expect. Does temp=temp//10 help ?

Comment: Also as the code stands it will just give you one iteration. You have to call code to do recursion. Break it into a def statement that does it for n. If successive calls give palindrome - you add again.

Comment: Closing this was a bad call. It was blatantly obvious what was wrong and expected output given. And suggestions I had added in comments before answering made sense. The code was complete. Error reproducable.

Comment: (I should have said - "don't give a palindrome" - add again..)

Comment: Did my comments and answer help you? If so would you care to accept the answer? Let me know if there is anything else. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def palCheck(num):
  strnum = str(num)
  strrev = ''.join(reversed(strnum))
  if strnum == strrev:
      return num
  else:
      return palCheck(num + int(strrev))

num=int(input())
print(palCheck(num))
```

See it in action [here](https://code.sololearn.com/ck0mcomkny0I/#py)